# Inherit from DropDownList and add a Validator, possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

I've already created my custom textbox control inheriting from it and all is fine and dandy. However, I'm having an issue trying the same thing with a DropDownList. I've searched for about 2 hours in Google and all the results I get are either crappy links or some (uncomplete) suggestions on creating a composite control and adding the DropDownList inside, but that also means that I have to expose all the events and properties that I use, which I find pretty overkill for what I need to do, which is to add a validator of any kind *next* to my DropDownList control.

To illustrate, this is what I'm attempting to do:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Blah
{
    public class ExtendedDropDownList : DropDownList
    {

        private DropDownList _self;
        private CustomValidator _cv;
        public bool Required { get; set; }
        public String FieldName { get; set; }

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            _cv = new CustomValidator()
            {
                ControlToValidate = ID,
                EnableClientScript = false,
                ValidationGroup = ValidationGroup,
                ValidateEmptyText = true
            };
            _cv.ServerValidate += new ServerValidateEventHandler(_cv_ServerValidate);
            Controls.Add(_cv);
        }

        private void _cv_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
        {
            if (Required && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(args.Value))
            {
                args.IsValid = false;
                _cv.ErrorMessage = "The field <strong>" + FieldName + "</strong> is required.";
                return;
            }            
        }

    }
}
```

And it throws an exception that the DropDownList cannot have secondary controls. How come? if the TextBox allows it?

Is there any way to do this same thing without creating the composite control and rewriting the wheel? (yes, pun intended :P). I assume I could get away with creating the control and then writing it in the rendering phase AFTER the DropDownList is rendered, but I can't find out how to do it and if it's even possible (though a hack, I'm short on time on a form generator I need to finish and this is taking too long and making me feel really tired :(... you guys know I come to SO when I've used up all the resources available).

Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: have you done a google search on the following `C# adding validator to DropDownList` it yields tons of results http://forums.asp.net/t/1296491.aspx?required+field+validator+for+dropdownlist

Comment: Yes I did, but it only talks about adding it on HTML code. I need to have it as a server control, not as an user control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I managed to do it the way I wanted, but with a bit of help from the container's page:

I had to add this to my aspx page:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phValidators" />
```

And then here's the finished control, which adds the validator to the Page's validators placeholder I created, not the control itself:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Blah
{
    public class ExtendedDropDownList : DropDownList
    {
        private CustomValidator _cv;
        public bool Required { get; set; }
        public String FieldName { get; set; }
        public String ValidatorPlaceHolder { get; set; }

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            _cv = new CustomValidator()
            {
                ControlToValidate = ID,
                EnableClientScript = false,
                ValidationGroup = ValidationGroup,
                Display = ValidatorDisplay.None,
                ValidateEmptyText = true
            };
            _cv.ServerValidate += new ServerValidateEventHandler(_cv_ServerValidate);
            if (Parent.FindControl(ValidatorPlaceHolder) != null)
                Parent.FindControl(ValidatorPlaceHolder).Controls.Add(_cv);
            else
                throw new Exception("Cannot find asp:PlaceHolder inside parent with ID '" + ValidatorPlaceHolder + "'");
            base.OnInit(e);
        }

        private void _cv_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
        {
            if (Required && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(args.Value))
            {
                args.IsValid = false;
                _cv.ErrorMessage = "The field <strong>" + FieldName + "</strong> is required.";
                return;
            }            
        }

    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone out :)